# Cast entities implicitly with EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, implicit-conversion, ef-core-2.2

Suppose I have following entities

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {
 public Guid Id { get;set; }
 public string Prop1 { get;set; }
 public long Prop2 { get;set; }
 public byte Type_Id { get;set; }
}

public class Type1 : BaseEntity { }

public class Type2 : BaseEntity { }

public class Type3 : BaseEntity {
  public long? Prop3 { get;set; }
}
```

And following context mapping:

```
builder.ToTable("Entities").HasDiscriminator(a => a.Type_Id)
                .HasValue<Type1>((byte)Types.Type1)
                .HasValue<Type2>((byte)Types.Type2)
                .HasValue<Type3>((byte)Types.Type3);
// in DbContext
public DbSet<BaseEntity> Entities { get; set; }
```

I want to create get IQueryable from DB (all records) Type1 and Type2 will have null in Prop3 ,
I do the following:

```
public DbSet<BaseEntity> DBSet { get;set; }
private static readonly MethodInfo FromSqlMethodInfo = typeof(RelationalQueryableExtensions).GetTypeInfo().GetDeclaredMethods("FromSql").Single(mi => mi.GetParameters().Length == 3);
public IQueryable<Type3> GetEntities(IEnumerable<Guid> ids) {
                RawSqlString sql = @"select [Id]
          ,[Prop1]
          ,[Prop2]
          ,[Prop3]
          ,[Type_Id]
            from [dbo].[Entities] where Id in (select item from @Ids)";
                var ids = new SqlParameter("@Ids", SqlDbType.Structured);
                ids.TypeName = typeof(Guid).Name.ToLowerInvariant() + "_item_list";
                ids.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                ids.Value = CreateItemList(tpIds);
                var param = new object[] { ids };
                var conversion = from s in DBSet select (Type3)s;
                var result = conversion.Provider.CreateQuery<Type3>(Expression.Call(null, FromSqlMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Type3)), conversion.Expression,
                   Expression.Constant(sql), Expression.Constant(param)));
                return result;
            }


var query = GetEntities(someIds);
var result = query.OrderBy(m => m.Type_Id).Skip(skip).Take(take).ToList();
```

And query executes successfully, but when ToLIst is called, Exception is thrown:
Unable to cast object of type 'Type1' to type 'Type3', which is quite expected, since we not telling how it should be converted...so the question is: can such trick be done with EF Core ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so for now only possible solution is to create one more entity with all properties required,

```
public class NewEntity {
 public Guid Id { get;set; }
 public string Prop1 { get;set; }
 public long Prop2 { get;set; }
 public byte Type_Id { get;set; }
 public long? Prop3 { get;set; }
}
```

add new DbSet to context

```
public DbSet<NewEntity> NewEntities { get; set; }
```

Map it to old table and update context configuration properly,
to avoid redundant columns generation (in this scenario EF will probaly
try to add new columns with names NewEntity_Prop1 , NewEntity_Prop2 etc..
as well as Foreign keys and indexes

```
public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<NewEntity> builder) {
    builder.ToTable("Entities");
    builder.Property(m => m.Prop1).HasColumnName("Prop1");
    builder.Property(m => m.Prop2).HasColumnName("Prop2");
    builder.Property(m => m.Type_Id).HasColumnName("Type_Id");
    builder.HasOne<BaseEntity>().WithOne().HasForeignKey<NewEntity>(e => e.Id);
}
```

Or create View

```
 public DbQuery<NewEntity> NewEntities { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
 modelBuilder.Query<NewEntity>().ToView("NewEntities");
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use implicit Overload Cast Operators. [Here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/explicit) is a link to help you.

Comment: Hi @nAviD ,and how can I tell EF to use overloaded operator?

Comment: when your class has implicit operator it should be castable to target class automatically. Although I have not test it on EF.
Another approach would be using AutoMapper

Comment: @da_sann I just forgot to mention you in my previous comment.

Comment: Ok, this won't work since EF provides casting only via [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)
which is not possible in this scenario, and AutoMapper does not solves the problem..for some reason due, to some EF internal logic, still getting same Exception (stacktrace is differs a bit though...)